# Como colocar 2 loop dentro de uma lista? ou um segundo loop para uma segunda lista

Tags: java

Esse é um programa que verifica entre 1 a 100 quais números são divisíveis por 3 e também conta a sua quantidade, tudo em cima desta formula:

```
a=n*n;  
b=a+?;
```

Essa interrogação é onde queria fazer o loop para por qualquer número desde 1 a 100.

Código:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

List<Long> Lista1 = new ArrayList();

for (long n = 1; n <= 100; n++) {

long a,b;

a = n*n; 
b = a+2;

if((b  % 3) == 0) {
    Lista1.add(b);
   } 

}
    System.out.println("Quantidade Números: "+Lista1.size());
    System.out.println("Divisível por 3: "+Lista1);

  }
}
```

Funciona normalmente:
[image: Funciona normalmente..]

Não consigo fazer um loop no "b".
`b = a+2;` é igual a 67 números...
Se mudar:
`b = a+3;` é igual a 33 números.. (quantidade)
Mudou, ou seja, precisaria de um Print, com uma lista de 1 a 100 de todas as quantidades conforme a formula é mudada (se conseguir mudar a soma dessa formula com um loop).
o `b` sendo `(a+1) = 0`.  Nenhum número dentre 1 a 100 é divisível por 3.

Agora se tivesse feito uma lista, de 1 a 3 dessa "formula com loop".

resultado:

> 1 = 0
>
> 2 = 67
>
> 3 = 33

ou seja...

```
b = a+1; = 0  
b = a+2; = 67  
b = a+3; = 33
```

para um entendimento melhor:

a = n*n; = número x número = 1*1 = 1
b = a+2; = 1+2 = 3

a = n*n; = número x número = 2*2 = 4
b = a+2; = 4+2 = 5

a = n*n; = número x número = 57*57 = 3249
b = a+2; = 3249+2 = 3251

Resposta foi Solucionada Obrigado!

Comment: Pra falar a verdade eu até agora não entendi a relação da formula com achar divisiveis por 3 entre 1 e 100, que alias, pode ser feito de [**maneira bem mais simples**](https://ideone.com/LTxNHX). Talvez se editar e explicar melhor o funcionamento dessa fórmula, ajude a compreender o problema.

Comment: Realmente não faz muito sentido. Se você quer saber quais numeros entre 1 e 100 são divisíveis por 3, então por que tem números maiores do que 100 nos resultados?

Comment: é simples, tem números maiores por causa da formula...

Comment: Não é simples, talvez seja para você, mas pra gente que não sabe muito bem o que você está desenvolvendo, fica complicado de entender, se não for passado com mais detalhes.

Comment: blz eu acabei de editar o final da questão vê lá...

Comment: Então você não quer verificar diviseis por 3 entre 1 e 100, o contexto da pergunta não condiz com o algoritmo. Se é de 1 a 100, o maior divisivel por 3 é 99, conforme pode ser visto pelo link que postei.

Comment: quero sim é que então está difícil pra entender mesmo... e talvez não esteja explicando corretamente... mas precisaria sim de verificar quais números são divisiveis por 3, no programa sem a outro "loop" que eu quero está funcionando normalmente... mais eu precisaria do "loop" que seria um adicional...

Comment: Pois é, sem entender o problema, fica complicado até de elaborar uma solução como resposta. Se quer achar divisiveis por 3 entre 1 e 100, o algoritmo é o que postei no link. Seu código está fazendo outra coisa que eu nem entendi até agora.

Comment: vou postar outro código pra vc entender o que eu quero... ok... diegofm

Comment: Não é só o código que é o problema, falta você explicar melhor o que está fazendo. Na pergunta diz *"verifica entre 1 a 100 quais números são divisíveis por 3 e também conta a sua quantidade"¨*, e a resposta abaixo faz isso perfeitamente. Explique melhor em que consiste o problema, o enunciado não está passando isso de forma que dê pra entender outra coisa diferente da resposta abaixo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Não entendi muito bem o que você quer fazer.
Mas veja se isso resolve:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    List<Long> lista = null;

    for (long j = 1; j <= 5; j++) {
        lista  = new ArrayList<>();
        for (long n = 1; n <= 100; n++) {
            long a = n*n;
            long b = a+j;
            if((b % 3) == 0) {
                lista.add(b);
            }
        }
        System.out.println("J: "+j);
        System.out.println("Quantidade Números: "+lista.size());
        System.out.println("Divisível por 3: "+lista);
    }
 }
```

Comment: @WilliamKarl você não pode editar uma resposta colocando uma outra pergunta. Entenda, essa dúvida que você está tendo é uma outra pergunta. Você tem que esperar até você poder fazer uma nova pergunta e então fazê-la. Se você misturar tudo vai confundir outros leitores. Apesar de você ter feito a pergunta, outras pessoas podem se beneficiar da resposta. Por sinal, tente editar a pergunta desse post para que ela fique mais clara para os futuros leitores. Sua pergunta está marcada como pendente, tente resolver a pendência.

Comment: @WilliamKarl o limite de perguntas provavelmente está sendo aplicado por causa da qualidade das que postou atualmente, suas perguntas estão sendo fechadas e negativas. Procure caprichar um pouco mais. Tente entender o problema antes de postar, tente fazer um [mcve], defina bem o texto, revise antes de publicar. Siga as recomendações passadas pelos usuários, melhore o que for for preciso. Sem mudar o sentido pode melhorar as perguntas já existentes e tentar reverter os votos. Mas cuidado para não piorar a situação mudando o sentido da pergunta ou burlar o funcionamento do sistema.

Answer (score 0):

Se seu objetivo é imprimir os números divisíveis por 3 de 1 a 100, isso poderia ser feito de forma bem mais simples:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

List<Long> Lista1 = new ArrayList();

    for (long n = 3; n <= 100; n+=3) {
        Lista1.add(n);
    }

    System.out.println("Quantidade Números: "+Lista1.size());
    System.out.println("Divisível por 3: "+Lista1);

}
```

Comment: entendo mas isso não é o que eu preciso =( é encontrar divisíveis por 3 entre 1 a 100 dentro de uma "fórmula".

Comment: encontrar números divisíveis por 3 entre 1 a 100 é simples.. agora dentro de uma formula com "loop" que é difícil e não estou conseguindo entende... obrigado pela respostas!!